# Can I install A used xbox one game* (*Has not been used online)

Tags: xbox-one

The Disc has not been played online and is not linked to anyone's account.

Comment: Please consider the properties of a disc, would an Xbox realistically be able to know that a disc has been in another Xbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will have no problems using the disc.
>
> When the Xbox One was first announced, Microsoft introduced a model
>   where newly purchased retail games would be licensed similarly to
>   downloadable titles; you wouldn't need the disc to play if installed,
>   and you'd be able to download and play the game with your Live account
>   on any Xbox One console. However, this restricted used games, in that
>   if you wanted to sell a retail game you'd have to go through a special
>   deauthorization process that would only be offered at certain
>   retailers (like GameStop) and would only be available with the game's
>   publisher's consent.
>
> Backlash to that model led to Microsoft adopting the same model as
>   every other console, past and present: if you have the physical game
>   media, you can play the game. In the Xbox One's case, you can still
>   install retail games to your hard drive, but you'll need the disc in
>   the tray to play.

Souce: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230468/158613

Comment: @FarazMajid If Mano's post answered your question, you can select it by clicking the checkmark next to it. It's the best way of showing your appreciation!